# Struts2 validation interceptor going to xhtml document

Tags: validation, xhtml, struts2, action, interceptor

**Background:** I am using Struts2 with the REST and Convention plugins, so about 99% of my settings are in the classes I write and not in xml files. With Convention, you can configure your server and client side validations with Annotations on the Method, for example, The Account Create method I am using looks like this:

```
@Validations(
        requiredFields = {
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "userName", message = "You must enter a value for field."),
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "firstName", message = "You must enter a value for field."),
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "lastName", message = "You must enter a value for field."),
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "password", message = "You must enter a value for field.")
        },
        emails = {@EmailValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "email", message = "You must enter a value for email.")},
        stringLengthFields = {
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, trim = true, minLength = "6", maxLength = "16", fieldName = "userName", message = "Username must be at least 6 letters."),
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, trim = true, minLength = "8", maxLength = "16", fieldName = "password", message = "Password must be at least 8 characters.")
        }
)
public String create() {
    //create the account
}
```

This works great, The javascript is pushed properly to the JSP, the form is validated before they hit submit, and the server-side validation works great as well, If all conditions are met, the `create()` method is called properly and everything works.

The problem lies when the client-side validation is bypassed and fails on the server-side validation. All the documentation tells me that the Validation interceptor sends the user back to the form with the proper field-errors set so that the user can fix their problem, but in my app, it simply redirects to a completely blank page.

**The Question**  - How do I tell the validation interceptor where the form is to redirect to so that the values can be filled in and the fieldErrors can be properly set?

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your configuration it's hard to tell what went wrong.

My guess is that you only configured the validation interceptor for your action
Example:

```
// this is wrong
<action name="doSomething" class="DoSomethingAction">
   <interceptor-ref name="validation">
   </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

Here only the validation interceptor is called but not the other interceptors like workflow

```
// this is better
<action name="doSomething" class="DoSomethingAction">
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
   </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```